# SQL Round number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have numbers with 2 decimals like 12.09. I want to round all to x9.90 or xx9.90.

I have this code to round to xxx.90:

```
UPDATE x
SET y = ROUND(col,1,2) + 
CASE 
WHEN y -(ROUND(col,1,2)) BETWEEN .00 AND .89 THEN .90
ELSE .90
END;
```

Comment: What is the type of `col`?  Note that using `BETWEEN` is inherently dangerous, for any type that can have varying levels of precision; [this blog talks about date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), but you have the potential to run into it here.  For all ranges, use lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive (`<`) conditions.

Comment: This isn't anything related to time. It's just one prices column.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you run into the exact same type of problem with any range over any type that supports varying levels of precision (ie, anything that isn't an integer, and even dealing with integer ranges may benefit from stating ranges the way I suggest).  For instance, your code is only good so long as SQL only uses 2-digit `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` types, which you may not have complete control over.  Do ranges the way I suggest, and your code would be good for _any_ precision, and for any shenanigans the DB may pull on you.

Comment: MySQL [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) takes only two parameters, what are you expecting from third one? Do you want everything that does not math `x9.90` to be rounded up, so both `9.99` and `17.45` will become `19.90`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
SET col = col +
    CASE WHEN
        MOD(col, 10) <= 9.9
    THEN
        9.9 - MOD(col, 10) -- for x0.00 - x9.90
    ELSE
        19.9 - MOD(col, 10) -- for x9.91 - x9.99
    END
```

Comment: Can you share it on mysql syntax?

Comment: What do you mean? This is mysql

Comment: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mytable SET col = col + CASE WHEN MOD(col, 10) <= 9.9 ' at line 1" I'm using mysql 5.5